# How to append elements to an array in a program in C?

Tags: c

I want the user to input values of elements to an array of 10 `int`s. Then I want to print out all the indexes of the values of the elements which when divided by 5 give 0.

I've tried doing it like this, but it's not working. How do I append the i's into an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int i;
    int index[10] = {};

    printf("Input %d values into the array:\n", N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] % 5 == 0){
            index[10] += i;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", index);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have declared index as an array that can hold exactly 10 ints.  It cannot hold more, and cannot grow to hold more.

Comment: There are many data structures you can use, but you need to build them yourself.  The simplest way to get an array that can. be grown dynamically is to use `realloc`.  But in your case it seems you could just declare `int index[20]`, since it appears that 20 will be large enough for what you are trying to do.  (It's not clear to me if `int index[11]` might be sufficient; are you just summing the indices into the last element of the array?)

Comment: I think the i is different through each iteration, but I don't know how to save them and then print them out later all at once.

Comment: Aside: `int index[10] = {};` is not valid standard C.  Use `int index[10] = {0};` to zero fill all.

Comment: `printf("%d", index);` should warn when all warnings are enabled.  Save time.  Enable all warnings to see that problem.

Comment: I don't want to sum them, just print them out, for example if they input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 i want to print out 4,9 since those are the indexes of the values divisible by 5

Comment: I wrote you an answer but your example output seems wrong.  It's index 0 and 5 that are divisible by 5 which are the values 1 and 6.  It's fine if you want to offset it, of course, but that is not the problem you describe.

Comment: I want the values checked if divisible by 5 and then pritning out the indexes of those values

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new index for the second array and solve the problem. But is better to make it in different loops.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
    #define N 10
    
    int main()
    {
    
    int a[N];
    int index[N] = {};
    //o will be the index for index array
    int o = 0;
    
    printf("Input %d values into the array:\n", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    
        if (a[i] % 5 == 0){
            index[o] = i;
            o++;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i<o;i++){
        printf("%i",index[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: Why does this print out a 0 at the end?

Comment: sorry i writed i<=o and is i<o

Comment: Now isnt printing the 0 at the end. It was printing that, because in the array i was accesing one value more than the last.

Comment: This seems to be op's preferred answer.  You should fix the non-standard initialization {} or just leave initialization out as you keep track of values that are defined with `o`.  Localize the first `i` in the loop otherwise you will get a warning of shadowing with the 2nd loop.  Like my answer, you should check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise `a[i]` might be undefined.

Comment: True. Im going to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment clarified the intention of your code so here is how solve it directly without the restoring to dynamic memory allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

int main(void) {
    int result[N];
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int d;
        if(scanf("%d", &d) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (!(d % 5)) {
            result[n++] = i;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%s", result[i], i + 1 < n ? "," : "\n");
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" | ./a.out
4,9
```

Comment: I want it to print out 4 and 9, cause of 5 and 10 are the only divisible by 5

Comment: index 0 is divisible by 5 and the value is clearly 1.   So you wan index + 2 divisible by 5?  While you figure that out I updated code to do that.

Comment: I want to check if the values are divisble by 5, not the indexes. Just print out the indexes of those values.

Comment: Revised the code.  All set?

Comment: The other answer solves it. Thanks !